# flutter Firebase order by key that contains only one part

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve all entries that contain a specific key. The Firebase entries consist of two keys joined together. In this example, I want to retrieve all entries that contain the key `abc123`.

```
Database:
    - xyz123abc123
    - abc123uvw123
```

Code:

```
String searchForKey = abc123

FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
    .child("note")
    .orderByKey()
    .equalTo(searchForKey*).once()         //something like that
    .then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent){
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = databaseEvent.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
        values.forEach((key,values) {
        //...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is an `endsWith()` method. However, such an operation is not supported by Firebase. Besides that, there are no wildcards in Firebase. So you cannot use something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
    .child("note")
    .orderByKey()
    .equalTo(searchForKey*).once() 
    //
```

The Realtime Database queries can only do prefix matching, meaning finding strings that start with a certain substring. There is currently no operation for postfix matching.

In such cases as yours, a common workaround would be to add two properties under a single node. One will contain the code, and the second one will contain the reversed code:

```
db
|
--- notes
     |
     --- nodeId
          |
          --- code: xyz123abc123
          |
          --- reverse: 321cba321zyx
```

And then query the `notes` node twice, once using `abc123` and the second time using the reverse `321cba`, and join the result on the client:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
    .child("notes")
    .orderByChild("code")
    .startAt("abc123").endAt("abc123\uf8ff")
```

And the second query:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
    .child("notes")
    .orderByChild("reverse")
    .startAt("321cba").endAt("321cba\uf8ff")
```

To be able to get the desired results, please note that the query is ordered by value and not by key.